# Check if one of the words in my array exists in my MySQL database [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

CODE:

```js
// Get message from chat and replace characters.
const messageReplaced = m.message.conversation.replace(/[^a-z0-9À-ú]/gi, ' ')

// Split Text using empty space
function splitStr(str, separator) {
  // Function to split string
  const string = str.split(separator);
  console.log(string);
}

// Initialize string
const str = messageReplaced
const separator = " ";

// Function call
splitStr(str, separator);
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Based on the output, I need to check each array (string[0], string[1], ...) one by one if it exists within an item in my database using a query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = (string[0], string[1], ...)
```

*I tried something like that, but no success.*

```
var i = 0; i < check.length; i++
```

Comment: What mysql library are you using?

Comment: You can't use `=` with a list of values, you have to use `WHERE id IN (...)`

Comment: @Barmar what would the code look like using this?

Comment: @code default lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splitStr()` should return the array, not log it. Although it's not clear why you need this functions, since it's exactly the same as calling `split()`.

Make a string containing as many `?` placeholders as you have values in the `string` array, then use that in a prepared statement.

```
let ids = messageReplaced.split(' ').map(Number);
let placeholders = Array(ids.length).fill('?').join(',');
let query = `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (${placeholders})`;
connection.query(query, ids, function(res, err) {
    if (err) {
        // report error
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1

Comment: code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN ('?,?,?,?,?,?,?',?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Comment: Sorry, the second argument to `db.query()` should be `ids`, not `placeholders`.

Comment: code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN ('1 2 3 4 5 6 7',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
}

Comment: I don't see any way that could happen. How did both `ids` and `placeholders` end up in the SQL?

Comment: I really do not know @barmar

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(query)`? It should be `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: I type this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

output 
[
  '1', '2', '3',
  '4', '5', '6',
  '7'
]

Return This: SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: And `console.log(ids)` shows `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']`?

Comment: yes 

query: `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`
ids:  `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']`

Comment: I can't explain it if you're using the `node-mysql` library. Each `?` in the SQL should be replaced by the corresponding element of `ids`.

Comment: what library u recommend to do that?

Comment: I'm not recommending anything, I'm explaining that that is what my code is supposed to do.

Comment: Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: You could use `WHERE id IN (${ids})` in `query`, but that's not as safe from SQL-injection.

Comment: Using `WHERE id IN (${ids})` works. but not show any result

Comment: If you log `query` and then execute it by hand, do you get anything?